# Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity" given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, one-to-many, symfony4

I try to insert records with relations OneToMany-ManyToOne, but I got error.

```
Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\Question" given.
```

I have next entities `question` and `answer`.

```
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="question", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $answers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Answer[]
 */
public function getAnswers(): Collection
{
    return $this->answers;
}

public function addAnswer(Answer $answer): self
{
    if (!$this->answers->contains($answer)) {
        $this->answers[] = $answer;
        $answer->setQuestion($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeAnswer(Answer $answer): self
{
    if ($this->answers->contains($answer)) {
        $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
        if ($answer->getQuestion() === $this) {
            $answer->setQuestion(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

Entity `Answer`

```
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $is_correct;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $question;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getText(): ?string
{
    return $this->text;
}

public function setText(string $text): self
{
    $this->text = $text;

    return $this;
}

public function getIsCorrect(): ?bool
{
    return $this->is_correct;
}

public function setIsCorrect(bool $is_correct): self
{
    $this->is_correct = $is_correct;

    return $this;
}

public function getQuestion(): ?question
{
    return $this->question;
}

public function setQuestion(?Question $question): self
{
    $this->question = $question;

    return $this;
}
```

}

My form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Question::class,
            'choice_label' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Question'
        ));
    $builder
        ->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => AnswerType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference'  => false,
));
    $builder
        ->add('create', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Add', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']]);


}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Question::class
    ]);
}
```

My fragment of controller

```
 $question = new Question();
 $answer = new Answer();
 $question->addAnswer($answer);
 $form1 = $this->createForm(QuestionAnswerType::class, $question);
 $form1->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($question);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

The error pointer at next line

```
 $form1->handleRequest($request);
```

I know I have problem with my controller, but I don't know how resolve it.

I don't get it how right insert records with relations OneToMany-ManyToOne. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason that you are seeing this error is due to the fact that in your `Question` class you have defined the `title` field as a Text type (`@ORM\Column(type="text")`).

However in your Form you have defined the form field `title` as an `EntityType` this is the reason I think why you are seeing this error.

You can fix this by changing the database mapping of the title field in your `Question` class **or** you could change your Form to use a `TextType` instead of an `EntityType`

Hope this helps

Comment: I changed type in entity as an "string", but I still get error.

Comment: You should look at Kapil's answer I think that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do changes into two places.

1) First change into "Question" class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $title;
```

2) Second into your form class replace "EntityType::class" with "TextType::class" and remove 'class' and 'choice_label' attribute from title

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Question'
        ));
    ..... your other code ...   
}
```

Comment: I got it. But I need use EntityType.

Comment: EntityType is only used when you have relationship with other table. Here "title" field is not associated with any one and it's a simple text type.

Comment: I have a relationship OneToMany-ManyToOne between tables question and answer.

Comment: True. For that you have used   "private $answers;" .  "title" column has no association with other table. It's  indepenand column. Hope you get it. :)

Comment: What do I must use instead title for EntityType?

Comment: Looks like you need `TextType` as @temp suggested.

Comment: When you want to use EntityType that mean you relate data with some other table. Assume county state example. state table have countryId  field that you can relate with country table. Only that countryId field you can use as  EntityType. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

In class Question __toString function is missing

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->property-to-show;
}
```